# Google showing description from iframe on a page

Tags: seo, google-search

I have facebook login on my page and I recently noted that google search result shows up a fb's warning message in the site description, fb's javascript plugin adds a iframe to the page for FB login which has the content shown in the image inside its body tag. How do I get rid of the waring message on google?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to just use robots.txt and tell google not to crawl your login page.  Probably has very little SEO value anyways, if the only text google is picking up is the FB login code.  Google interprets javascript as it crawls your site, and in your case it has decided that the text from FB login is of high value.   Either build up the content of the page and wait for google to update its description (adding meta description wont hurt), or just no-index the page.